# MPI-Related Segmentation Fault for icpc But Not GCC

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, mpi, icc

I am trying to run a program compiled with Intel compilers. The program has both openMP and MPI code. The MPI code is a new addition to the program.

- Code compiled with gcc and OpenMPI (gcc-flavored, v1.8) runs and works correctly.
- Code compiled with icpc and Intel-Compiled OpenMPI seg faults with "Address Not Mapped" error

**OpenMPI (compiled with Intel) Error**

```
[ida3c03:22018] 63 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-btl-openib.txt / reg mem limit low
[ida3c03:22018] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
done!
[ida3c04:03329] *** Process received signal ***
[ida3c04:03329] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ida3c04:03329] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ida3c04:03329] Failing at address: 0x10
```

- Code compiled with icpc and Intel's own MPI seg faults as well with one of 2 errors

**Error 1**

```
 Could not find **ibv_destroy_qp in list of messages
 Could not find **ibv_destroy_qp in list of messages
 Could not find **ibv_destroy_qp in list of messages
 Could not find **ibv_destroy_qp in list of messages
 Could not find **ibv_destroy_qp in list of messages
 Could not find **vc_gen2_qp_finalize in list of messages
 Could not find **ibv_destroy_qp in list of messages
 Could not find **vc_gen2_qp_finalize in list of messages
 Could not find **vc_gen2_qp_finalize in list of messages
 Could not find **vc_gen2_qp_finalize in list of messages
 Could not find **vc_gen2_qp_finalize in list of messages
 Could not find **vc_gen2_qp_finalize in list of messages
 Fatal error in MPI_Finalize: Internal MPI error!, error stack:
 MPI_Finalize(311).................: MPI_Finalize failed
 MPI_Finalize(229).................:
 MPID_Finalize(140)................:
 MPIDI_CH3_Finalize(24)............:
 MPID_nem_finalize(63).............:
 MPID_nem_gen2_module_finalize(520):(unknown)(): Internal MPI error!
```

**Error 2**

```
recv desc error, 128, 0x9d0240
[mpiexec@ida3c03] control_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:717): assert (!closed) failed
[mpiexec@ida3c03] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@ida3c03] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:435): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@ida3c03] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:901): process manager error waiting for completion
```

The project is huge and would be difficult to show you all the MPI code, but I grepped out the MPI calls from one of the main files where I think the error occurs, in case that would be useful at all. I filled in actual variable names with "vector_#".

```
1172:  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
1173:  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numranks);
1174:  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
1315:  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
1593:  MPI_Allgather(&long_1,1,MPI_LONG,vector_1,1,MPI_LONG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
1594:  MPI_Allgather(&long_2, 1,MPI_LONG,vector_2, 1,MPI_LONG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);    
1624:  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
1655:  MPI_Bcast(buffer,long*[count],MPI_CHAR,count,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
1661:  MPI_Allgatherv(dnas_chars_send, long_2, MPI_CHAR,  char*,int*, long*, MPI_CHAR,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
1740:  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2013:  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
2064:  MPI_Allgather(&int,1,MPI_INT,int*,1,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2066:  MPI_Allgather(&int,1,MPI_INT,int*,1,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2068:  MPI_Allgather(&int,1,MPI_INT,int*,1,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2106:  MPI_Allgatherv(int*, int,MPI_INT,int* ,int*, int*, MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2107:  MPI_Allgatherv(int*, int,MPI_INT,int* ,int*, int*, MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2108:  MPI_Allgatherv(int*,int,MPI_INT,int*,int*,int*, MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2136:  MPI_Allgatherv(int*,int,MPI_INT,int*,int*,int*, MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2137:  MPI_Allgatherv(int*,int,MPI_INT,int*,int*,int*, MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2164:  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
2519:  MPI_Finalize();
```

But I don't understand why the code would be fine in gcc and then experience this error for icpc. The code is running on a cluster, and I don't have access to the backend nodes where the MPI processes are running.

Comment: Hi! Please google "Gcc address sanitizer".... chances are that your error is a problem with the way you access memory (buffer overflow/underflow) which happens no matter what compiler you use, but it only crashes with the intel compiler because memory allocation is more "strict" there....

Comment: Segfaults are easy, fun, and satisfying to track down; the more spectacular the program failure, the better. Unless you have a parallel debugger like ddt or totalview installed, easiest is to re-compile with a -g flag, set ulimit -c unlimited, run, and with running a debugger (gdb or idb will work fine) on the executable and the resulting core file(s) should tell you exactly what went wrong.  @dsign is completely correct about the likely gcc/icpc difference here, but in general, memory errors symptoms like segfaults can manifest very differently with very small changes in code/environment.

Comment: Both MPI implementations are failing in some InfiniBand verbs related code. That could indicate that there are still messages in transit at the time `MPI_Finalize()` is called and they probably refer freed (or garbled) memory areas. It could be some aggressive optimisation on the Intel's side. Try compiling with lower optimisation levels, even with `-O0`. If I were you, I would listen to Jonathan Dursi.

Comment: I am not sure how I would debug with gdb though considering I can't log in to the backend node and the process is too intensive for the login node. This might just be because I'm new to debugging MPI on clusters. I know of no other way to attach to the process though. If I just open the core dump in gdb using the object file that it fails in, trying a backtrace causes gdb to segfault.